# ASP.NET MVC erro ao apresentar campos data e hora na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ola
Estou com alguns problemas para presentar na View.

No banco de dados tenho estes dados gravados:

DataInicio: (datetime) 1998-11-16 00:00:00.000

DataFim: (datetime): 1998-11-16 00:00:00.000

HorarioEntrada (time): 09:00:00.0000000

HorarioSaida (time): 18:00:00.0000000

ValorHora (money): 50.00

O valor dos campos "ValorHora", "DataInicio" and "DataFim" não estão sendo apresentados na VIEW.

E o campo "HorarioEntrada" dispara este erro: "Input string was not in correct format"

Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Valor deve estar entre {1} e {2}")]
[Display(Name = "Valor hora extra")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public decimal? ValorHoraExtra { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Ínicio do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Fim do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Valor deve estar entre {0} e {1}")]
[Display(Name = "Valor hora")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public decimal? ValorHora { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name ="Horário de entrada")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name = "Horário de saída")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioSaida { get; set; }
```

View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFim, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFim, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorHora, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorHora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorHora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HorarioEntrada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorarioEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HorarioEntrada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HorarioSaida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorarioSaida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HorarioSaida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Outra coisa, no navegador, os campos data, não estão capturando o valor ao selecionar a data no calendário. Isso ocorre no Chrome. No Firefox, o calendário não existe.

O que esta errado no código para que esses erros ocorram?

Comment: Acho melhor você focar mais no problema em si, seu código está muito extenso. Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, é interessante dá uma lida no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender o funcionamento do site.

Comment: OK. deixei no código somente os campos que estão apresentando problemas

Answer (score 2):

Isto aqui não vai funcionar:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Ínicio do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Fim do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }
```

Para `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`, o `DisplayFormat` precisa ser, obrigatoriamente, `yyyy-MM-dd`, [pela especificação do `<input type="date">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html), [que segue o RFC3339](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339):

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Ínicio do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Fim do contrato")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }
```

Para valor financeiro, a `DataFormatString` também está errada:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Valor deve estar entre {0} e {1}")]
[Display(Name = "Valor hora")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public decimal? ValorHora { get; set; }
```

Deveria ser:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
public decimal? ValorHora { get; set; }
```

Mas prefiro usar `@Html.TextBoxFor` juntamente com [o JS jQuery Mask Money](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JQuery.MoneyMask/), cujo resultado visual fica melhor, então não uso `[DisplayFormat]` para campo financeiro.

Para os campos de hora, o `DateFormatString` se perde usando o seu formato:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name ="Horário de entrada")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Display(Name = "Horário de saída")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:HH:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioSaida { get; set; }
```

Troque para:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioSaida { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan? HorarioEntrada { get; set; }
```

Sobre o suporte destes campos no Firefox, aparentemente a Mozilla não aceita as especificações de campos de data e hora (patrocinadas pelo Google), então você terá que fazer a [inclusão do Webshim](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) no seu projeto para ter estes campos também no Firefox.